ModSecurity blocks after despite rule exclusions
I try to create a rule allowing any parameter value containing scrip%u0074 (Unicode value of t) to be passed. I create such a rule:
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@contains scrip%u0074" \
    "id:1234567,phase:1,pass,t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,logdata:'Bypass script',ctl:ruleRemoveTargetByTag=attack-xss,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=920220"

But other rules still block it. When I remove the part with t:..., it works, but the value sent to the web application is not script (Unicode replaced by utf-8), but still Unicode.
How can we improve that rule to avoid detection/blocking by other rules and replace unicode to utf-8?

CRS dev-on-duty here. It's dangerous to remove parts of the OWASP CRS depending on user input. It's a better idea to only remove specific arguments from a rule.
What arguments contain this scrip%u0074? Can you identify them?
ctl:ruleRemoveTargetByTag=attack-xss and ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=920220 don't work because you don't specify a target to remove, you only specify a rule.
To remove an argument (target) called name, use
ctl:ruleRemoveTargetByTag=attack-xss;ARGS:name and ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=920220;ARGS:name.
Place those rules BEFORE the CRS rules.
Other possibility:
To exclude an entire rule/tag use ctl:ruleRemoveByTag=attack-xss and ctl:ruleRemoveById=920220 instead, if you still want to use this kind of tuning.
Place those SecRule rules BEFORE the CRS rules.
See here: https://github.com/owasp-modsecurity/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#ctl
You can also (other possibility) remove an argument called "name" by removing it from a specific rule with:
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 920220 !ARGS:name
(Here we use the update and the !)
Place those SecRuleUpdate... directives AFTER the CRS rules include.
Please have a look at the CRS tuning documentation: https://coreruleset.org/docs/concepts/false_positives_tuning/
If you still have blocks, please open an issue in our GitHub repo and fill out the false positive template:
https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/issues

Yes, I want to do this in the context of a particular parameter, let's call a "name".

Then you can remove this argument "name" with: SecRuleUpdateTargetById 920220 !ARGS:name.

I improved my rule, but still, it is blocked:
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@contains scrip%u0074" \     "id:1234567,phase:1,pass,t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,logdata:'Bypass script',ctl:ruleRemoveByTag=attack-xss;!ARGS:name,ctl:ruleRemoveById=920220;!ARGS:name"

Now, we have a target we want to remove: name.
So we can write:
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@contains scrip%u0074" \     "id:1234567,phase:1,pass,t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,logdata:'Bypass script',ctl:ruleRemoveTargetByTag=attack-xss;ARGS:name,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=920220;ARGS:name"

I didn't check the rule or the encoding.
If it doesn't work can you try:
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 920220 !ARGS:name and
SecRuleUpdateTargetByTag "attack-xss" "!ARGS:name"
In contrast to the SecRule (first example above, to be placed BEFORE the CRS), the SecRuleUpdateTargetById must be included AFTER the CRS.
Also see https://coreruleset.org/docs/concepts/false_positives_tuning/,

OK, I think that I put the rules in the wrong file. Could you suggest which file should have the exclusion rules?

I tried to add SecRule before IncludeOptional /etc/modsecurity/.conf, ../crs-setup.conf and ../rules/.conf in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/security2.conf and still string is blocked. I added SecRuleUpdateTargetBy... after IncludOptional in the same file and got the same results- blocked.

So you added SecRule BEFORE the rules (../rules/.conf) or SecRuleUpdateTargetById AFTER the rules (../rules/.conf)... And you say you're still getting blocked? Do you have other rules that trigger? This is getting complicated now here. Can you please open an issue in our GitHub repo and fill out the false positive template? https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/issues

Just in case I copy a content secure2.conf file and ModSecurity version

`
SecDataDir /var/cache/modsecurity
SecRule ARGS:name "@contains scrip%u0074"
"id:1234567,phase:1,pass,t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,logdata:'Bypass script',ctl:ruleRemoveByTag=attack-xss;!ARGS:name,ctl:ruleRemoveById=920220;!ARGS:name"
    IncludeOptional /etc/modsecurity/*.conf

IncludeOptional /etc/apache2/modsecurity-crs/coreruleset-3.3.0/crs-setup.conf
IncludeOptional /etc/apache2/modsecurity-crs/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/*.conf
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 920220 !ARGS:name
SecRuleUpdateTargetByTag "attack-xss" "!ARGS:name"
`

ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.5 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured. ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.7.0"; loaded version="1.7.0" ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.39 "; loaded version="8.39 2016-06-14" ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.1" ModSecurity: YAJL compiled version="2.1.0" ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.12"
